# Paperclip wrong attachment url on validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, url, paperclip

I have a preview of attached image in my update form. The problem appears when user gets validation errors on attachment field. In this case image thumbnail url becomes as if an image was uploaded without any errors (it shows name of file that was not saved at server).

Here is how I get image url in my view:
`<%= image_tag(@product.photo.url(:medium)) %>`.

Controller:

```
def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.update_attributes(params[:product]) ? redirect_to('/admin') : render(:new)
end

def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  render :new
end
```

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  <...>

  @@image_sizes = {:big => '500x500>', :medium => '200x200>', :thumb=> '100x100>'}

  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => @@image_sizes, :whiny => false
  validates_attachment_presence :photo
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'], :message => I18n.t(:invalid_image_type)
  validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 1.megabytes, :message => I18n.t(:invalid_image_size, :max => '1 Mb')
  after_post_process :save_image_dimensions

  <...>

end
```

**UPD:** The simpliest solution is to add `@photo_file_url = @product.photo.url(:medium)` in controller's update action before `@product.update_attributes` and `<% @photo_file_url ||= @product.photo.url(:medium) %>` in the view.

Comment: Please include your code for your `edit` and `update` actions.

Comment: They are quite simple. Nothing but few CRUD tips (`Product.find(params[:id])` and `@product.update_attributes(params[:product])` for edit and update respectively).

Comment: It is a more common practice to edit your existing post with these updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had the same issue and here is what I had done (which seems a bit of a hack) but works and will show the default or previous image on update failure

```
after_validation :logo_reverted?

def logo_reverted?
  unless self.errors[:logo_file_size].blank? or self.errors[:logo_content_type].blank?
    self.logo.instance_write(:file_name, self.logo_file_name_was) 
    self.logo.instance_write(:file_size, self.logo_file_size_was) 
    self.logo.instance_write(:content_type, self.logo_content_type_was)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I think my solution is a little bit easier.

Comment: @skrafi - I agree that your solution is much easier but I couldn't get my delete and change to show up correctly because there is still a file in queue.  I felt as thought i would still have to check for errors to delete the file so that my delete ajax link would not show unless there was really a file there.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In my app I had similar issues, so I used:

```
<%= image_tag(@product.photo.url(:medium)) if @photo.valid? %>
```

That way nothing shows up if the Photo isn't valid (ie successfully created), but when you edit existing records the image is shown.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Using `@product.valid?` causes very strange issue in the new action (I use same view for both new and update actions). If I have `@product.valid?` somewhere in my view I also get `can't be blank` error on photo field. See [view code](http://pastie.org/1752064) and [the result](http://pastie.org/1752077) (before submit).

Comment: Hmm, did you try `if @product.errors.any?` instead? Not sure why it would matter but that is a weird error, so worth a shot...

Comment: I'm now using `@product.errors.any?` instead of `@product.valid?` in the code that I showed above. But the problem still occurs if I want to show a photo in the update action when I try to upload new photo and any error happen. Paperclip saves a photo only when a model has no errors. If it has any Paperclip gives url with file name that wasn't saved. She **UPD** in my question above for the only solution that I found to solve this.